# VSCode: Issue installing Gradle distribution

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[I am following this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) about building Java web applications in VSCode.

After I pressed F5 to debug my code, I received the error message `Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'.`.

Screenshot:

[image: VSCode Gradle Error]

Can anyone help me figure out why this error message is appearing?

Comment: formatted question into sentences, expanded image, made title more concise

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem on Linux.
My understanding is that VS Code wants to use the directory `/usr/share/java/gradle/` (which is contained in the environment variable `GRADLE_HOME`), whereas it should use `~/.gradle` instead.
I tried to fix it through the configuration files (such as `gradle-wrapper.properties`, `.vscode/settings.json` or `.settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs`) but without success.
The only workaround I found was to set the environment variable:

- if you want to do it for all your sessions (with the risk that it might break some other applications), put the following line into your `~/.bash_profile` and reboot:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=~/.gradle
```

- a less intrusive solution is to set the variable when launching VS Code:

```
env GRADLE_HOME=~/.gradle code
```

If you use a desktop entry, customize the relevant file. In my case (Arch Linux), this file is `/usr/share/applications/visual-studio-code.desktop`; so put the following line into it:

```
Exec=env GRADLE_HOME=~/.gradle code %f
```

and restart VS Code (twice if necessary).

I opened [an issue on Github](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/859).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download Gradle manually and use that you can configure some VS Code settings to reference your Gradle distribution:

1. set *java.import.gradle.wrapper.enabled* to false
2. keep *java.import.gradle.version* empty
3. point *java.import.gradle.home* to your unzip folder

Thanks to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gradle/issues/1125#issuecomment-996441654